# Laravel 5 Auto Generate Form Numbers / Identifiers

Tags: mysql, laravel, automation

Hi I have a Form which needs a unique form number. Basically what I need is before the form is submitted, the user is able to see what form number will that form submission will have. The form number should be unique.

What I'm thinking is I'll have another table which has a single row:

```
table:numbers
->id
->number
```

Then when the form loads I'll make an ajax request to show the current number and use it as form number then when the user submit, the number will be updated (increamented) since it is already used. But problem is I want the form number to formatted like `1, 2, 3 ..` so I added zerofill on database but when I fetch it it only show the number in my form without zeroes. Is there a better approach on this? I'm using MySQL

Thanks

Comment: should the form numbers be sequential or can it be random?

Comment: @MilanMaharjan can be randon as long as unique

Comment: Check out my answer, I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to handle this would be to create a new Form each time one is requested. It can get a sequential ID from the Primary Key. You will probably want to set a status so that you can then identify abandoned forms. So on create, set the form status as "new". Then once one is submitted set the status to "submitted". I would also use timestamps for these records as well.

This is how I handle orders. I create a new order every time someone begins the checkout process. I then can use these metrics to find the number of abandoned orders vs completed orders.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is first generate a random number ( say between 10000 adn 999999). Then check if it already exists in your main table( say main_form_table where column name is form_number). And also check if the number exists in the temp table you created (numbers). If it already exists in any of the table, regenerate the random number and check again, until a unique number is found.

Once a unique number is found you can store in in the temp table you created, so that if another form is trying to generate a random number this number cant be used. Once the form is submitted, you can deleted the random number entry from your temp table. This form number will now be stored in your main table, and cant be used again by other forms.

```
           do {
                $randomNumber = rand(10000, 999999);
                $numberInFromTable = MainFormTable::whereFormNumber($randomNumber)->get();
                $numberInTempTable = Number::whereId($randomNumber)->get();
            }while(!$numberInFromTable->isEmpty() || !$numberInTempTable->isEmpty());

            $number = new Number;
            $number->number = $randomNumber;
            $number->save();
```